# server is temporarily unavailable (503 error). httpd not found, need method to install httpd

Tags: apt, apache2

I am running a local web server with multiple web sites using shared ip. Recently I upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and I just now found that only one of my sites is working normally. I can't say for sure this problem did not exist at the time of the upgrade, but it wasn't too long ago that it was working.

`etc/hosts`

```
192.168.1.29    secondbase  
192.168.1.29    mattiefernworrix.lan  
192.168.1.29    mfwsandbox  
192.168.1.29    pinkpoodle  
192.168.1.29    mfwx
```

`secondbase` is the server name.

mattiefernworrix.lan works fine, the first in the list. The other three do not (mfwsandbox, pinkpoodle,and mfwx). Actually, that's not completely true. If I request a static html page, it comes up as expected. If I request a .php file, then it fails with the 503 message. The php files all get data from a mysql db.

So as far as I can determine, httpd is not running.

```
jking@secondbase:/sbin$ systemctl status httpd
Unit httpd.service could not be found.
```

So I tried to install httpd, which failed.

```
sudo apt-get update  
sudo apt-get install httpd  

Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done  
Package httpd is a virtual package provided by:  
  nginx-light 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1  
  nginx-full 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1  
  nginx-extras 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1  
  nginx-core 1.18.0-6ubuntu14.1  
  apache2 2.4.52-1ubuntu4.1  
  yaws 2.1.1+dfsg-1  
  webfs 1.21+ds1-12  
  tntnet 2.2.1-4build2  
  mini-httpd 1.30-2build1  
  micro-httpd 20140814-2.1  
  lighttpd 1.4.63-1ubuntu3  
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Package 'httpd' has no installation candidate
```

Finally, I tried to install the apache2 package

```
jking@secondbase:/sbin$ sudo apt-get install apache2

Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
apache2 is already the newest version (2.4.52-1ubuntu4.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 13 not upgraded.
```

Not sure where to go from here. Uninstall apache2 and then install it again?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Thanks for your response.

examples of log file msgs (combined):

```
192.168.1.29 - - [27/Aug/2022:16:36:22 -0700] "GET /index2.html HTTP/1.1" 200 318 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0"  
192.168.1.29 - - [27/Aug/2022:16:36:31 -0700] "GET /index.html HTTP/1.1" 200 318 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0"

192.168.1.29 - - [27/Aug/2022:16:37:24 -0700] "GET /search_msqli.php HTTP/1.1" 503 565 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0"  
[Sat Aug 27 16:37:24.856332 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 1101] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock (*) failed  
[Sat Aug 27 16:37:24.856459 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1101] [client 192.168.1.29:37158] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS

192.168.1.29 - - [27/Aug/2022:17:05:04 -0700] "GET /search_msqli.php HTTP/1.1" 503 565 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0"  
[Sat Aug 27 17:05:04.820227 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 4836] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock (*) failed  
[Sat Aug 27 17:05:04.820254 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 4836] [client 192.168.1.29:37160] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS

192.168.1.29 - - [27/Aug/2022:17:08:50 -0700] "GET /payments_msqli.php HTTP/1.1" 503 565 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:104.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/104.0"  
[Sat Aug 27 17:08:50.349738 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 1100] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock (*) failed  
[Sat Aug 27 17:08:50.349776 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 1100] [client 192.168.1.29:37172] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

I found this previous post

[phpmyadmin "503 service not available": Unbuntu 20.04, MySQL 8.0](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335032/phpmyadmin-503-service-not-available-unbuntu-20-04-mysql-8-0)

> Figured it out. In case anyone else has this problem, I had to add   the following block to my submdomain VirtualHost, phpmyadmin starts   showing up on the subdomain again:
>
> <FilesMatch ".php$">
> SetHandler "proxy:unix:/var/run/php/php7.4->fpm.username.sock|fcgi://localhost/"
> <`/`FilesMatch>

I looked and I don't have a `/var/run/php/` directory.

```
jking@secondbase:~$ php -v  
PHP 8.1.2 (cli) (built: Jul 21 2022 12:10:37) (NTS)
```

#### Additional Problem Symptom

Hi, I just realized that what I said was the only working web site has only html files, no php files. I added the info.php file and got the 503 response. So ALL of the sites being served are unable to process php files and respond with the 503 error message.

#### Check for libapache2-mod-php

I haven't done anything but the upgrade to 22.04. I assumed that it would be updated with whatever was necessary since it was an existing install (package). Was I wrong to make that assumption? This was all working prior to the upgrade. I've also run apt-get update a number of times since.

Checking into it:

```
jking@secondbase:~$ dpkg -s libapache2-mod-php  
Package: libapache2-mod-php  
Status: install ok installed  
Priority: optional  
Section: php  
Installed-Size: 18  
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>  
Architecture: all  
Source: php-defaults (92ubuntu1)  
Version: 2:8.1+92ubuntu1  
Depends: libapache2-mod-php8.  
Description: server-side, HTML-embedded scripting language (Apache 2 module) (default)

 This package provides the PHP module for the Apache 2 webserver.

 PHP (recursive acronym for PHP: Hypertext Preprocessor) is a widely-used open source general-purpose scripting language that is especially suited for web development and can be embedded into HTML.

 This package is a dependency package, which depends on latest stable
 PHP version (currently 8.1).

Original-Maintainer: Debian PHP Maintainers <team+pkg-php@tracker.debian.org>
```

#### Version mismatch?

So the error message refers to php 7.4 `/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock (*) failed` while dpkg refers to php 8.1 `Version: 2:8.1+92ubuntu1`. Is there something that needs to be updated? Or something that needs to be uninstalled/removed?

John

#### Bring packages up to date

```
jking@secondbase:/var/log/apache2$ dpkg-query -l libapache2-mod-php8.1
||/ Name                  Version          Architecture Description
+++-=====================-================-============-=======================>  
ii  libapache2-mod-php8.1 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.3 amd64        server-side, HTML-embed>


jking@secondbase:/var/log/apache2$ dpkg-query -l libapache2-mod-php  
||/ Name               Version         Architecture Description  
+++-==================-===============-============-===========================>  
ii  libapache2-mod-php 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 all          server-side, HTML-embedded >  


jking@secondbase:/var/log/apache2$ dpkg-query -l libapache2-mod-php7.4
||/ Name                  Version      Architecture Description
+++-=====================-============-============-===========================>
un  libapache2-mod-php7.4 <none>       <none>       (no description available)


jking@secondbase:/var/log/apache2$ dpkg-query -l libapache2-mod-php8.0
||/ Name                  Version      Architecture Description
+++-=====================-============-============-===========================>
un  libapache2-mod-php8.0 <none>       <none>       (no description available)
```

Unfortunatly, made no apparent difference. Still complaining about PHP7.4 in the error.log file:

```
[Sun Aug 28 23:23:44.600963 2022] [proxy:error] [pid 6221] (2)No such file or directory: AH02454: FCGI: attempt to connect to Unix domain socket /run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock (*) failed

[Sun Aug 28 23:23:44.601007 2022] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 6221] [client 192.168.1.29:56866] AH01079: failed to make connection to backend: httpd-UDS
```

and I still have no `/run/php`directory.

#### Package status

```
jking@secondbase:~$ sudo  apt list --installed | grep php

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

libapache2-mod-php8.1/jammy-updates,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.3 amd64 [installed]  
libapache2-mod-php/jammy,jammy,now 2:8.1+92ubuntu1 all [installed]  
php-common/jammy,jammy,now 2:92ubuntu1 all [installed]  
php8.1-cli/jammy-updates,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]  
php8.1-common/jammy-updates,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]  
php8.1-opcache/jammy-updates,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]  
php8.1-readline/jammy-updates,now 8.1.2-1ubuntu2.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]

jking@secondbase:~$ sudo apt upgrade  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done  
Calculating upgrade... Done  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

jking@secondbase:~$ sudo apt update  
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease  
Get:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]                        
Hit:3 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                 
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]     
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]  
Fetched 324 kB in 1s (337 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done  
All packages are up to date.

jking@secondbase:~$ sudo apt update --fix-missing  
Hit:1 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy InRelease  
Hit:2 https://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                
Get:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates InRelease [114 kB]   
Get:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security InRelease [110 kB]
Get:5 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-backports InRelease [99.8 kB]  
Fetched 324 kB in 1s (319 kB/s)                                     
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done  
All packages are up to date.

jking@secondbase:~$ sudo apt install -f  
Reading package lists... Done  
Building dependency tree... Done  
Reading state information... Done  
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

Not sure where to go from here. I'll probably uninstall apache and reinstall.

Appreciate the effort. Thank you.

John

Comment: Based on the steps you’ve followed, it seems you’re doing this the hard way. What do your logs say? Check `/var/log/apache2`. It would also be good to familiarize yourself with the Debian/Ubuntu package names, as it seems you’ve done a bunch of stuff using CentOS package names 

Comment: Did you *install* PHP for Apache yet?  `php-cli` is not `libapache2-mod-php` which is what you need.

Comment: Make sure that your system is installing `libapache2-mod-php8.1` as well as `libapache2-mod-php`.  Make sure you also remove completely with `sudo apt purge` the additional `libapache2-mod-php7.4` and `libapache2-mod-php8.0` packages.  In 22.04, the only PHP available is PHP 8.1

Comment: Also, why is this tagged `12.04` which is an End of Life version?

Comment: Sorry, just an error on my part. Should be 22.04.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo a2enmod php8.1
sudo systemctl restart apache2
```